# If he stole/has stolen the money that day I saw him, he will probably leave the country soon

Tags: conditionals

Which is right?

> If he **stole** the money **that day I saw him**, he will probably leave the country soon.
> or
> If he **has stolen** the money **that day I saw him**, he will probably leave the country soon.

I'm not considering the third conditional here (if he **had stolen** the money **that day I saw him**, he would probably leave the country soon), because the third conditional says about unreal past. Here, as you may have already noticed a different story.

Comment: The first one is correct. Have you considered saying "If he stole the money **the** day I saw him, he will probably leave the country soon."?

Comment: Dubious, thank you! Yes, I think it is better to use "the". 

Which conditional is the sentence? It doesn't seem to fit to any of zero, first, second, third or mixed.

Comment: I don't understand your numbering of the conditionals, since there is no accepted system used in American schooling or discussions about grammar.  I think the basic answer to question is possibly that in all European languages, there are certain tense combinations that are usual in conditional sentences, but in unusual cases such as this one, which mixes the past with the future, other options are possible..  Because of this awkwardness, I would prefer to reword the sentence as: "If it turns out that he stole the money...." making the combination of tenses more typical.

Comment: It's not my "numbering of the conditionals" this is how we are taught it in schools. This is how we are taught by native speakers. I'm fed up with this numbering bacause they don't show many such as real past condition. Yes, I see that we can say "If it is true" or "If it turns out that". But why say it? We must have the opportunity to simply say "if X was true, then Y will be true" speculating/deducting about past and future. I believe if there is a need to say something, there has to be the way.

Comment: Vegawatcher, I hope now it is clear what I mean.